# Unable to unwrap data, invalid status CLOSED - Not using a proxy server

Tags: spring, tomcat

I am running Apache Tomcat 9.0.41 and I am encountering the following error. A quick search shows the most common cause is a misconfigured proxy server, except that I am not using a proxy server. I tried setting the keepAliveTimeout attribute on the connector to -1 and it did not resolve the issue.

```
26-Apr-2021 13:03:38.983 FINE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-5] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill Before fill(): [true], parsingRequestLine: [true], parsingRequestLinePhase: [0], parsingRequestLineStart: [0], byteBuffer.position() [0]
26-Apr-2021 13:03:38.983 FINE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-5] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.populateReadBuffer Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@3f3904ed:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@2bb2feb7:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=localhost/127.0.0.1:8443 remote=/10.255.106.212:51956]], Read from buffer: [0]
26-Apr-2021 13:03:38.983 FINE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-5] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@3f3904ed:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@2bb2feb7:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=localhost/127.0.0.1:8443 remote=/10.255.106.212:51956]], Read direct from socket: [0]
26-Apr-2021 13:03:38.983 FINE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-5] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill Received []
26-Apr-2021 13:03:38.983 FINE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-5] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@3f3904ed:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@2bb2feb7:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=localhost/127.0.0.1:8443 remote=/10.255.106.212:51956]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [OPEN]
26-Apr-2021 13:03:38.984 FINE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-5] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.release Pushed Processor [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor@62e6798c]
26-Apr-2021 13:03:38.984 FINE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-5] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.registerReadInterest Registered read interest for [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@3f3904ed:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@2bb2feb7:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=localhost/127.0.0.1:8443 remote=/10.255.106.212:51956]]
26-Apr-2021 13:03:39.005 FINE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Processing socket [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@2bb2feb7:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=localhost/127.0.0.1:8443 remote=/10.255.106.212:51956]] with status [OPEN_READ]
26-Apr-2021 13:03:39.005 FINE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Found processor [null] for socket [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@2bb2feb7:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=localhost/127.0.0.1:8443 remote=/10.255.106.212:51956]]
26-Apr-2021 13:03:39.005 FINE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Popped processor [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor@62e6798c] from cache
26-Apr-2021 13:03:39.005 FINE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-6] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill Before fill(): [true], parsingRequestLine: [true], parsingRequestLinePhase: [0], parsingRequestLineStart: [0], byteBuffer.position() [0]
26-Apr-2021 13:03:39.005 FINE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-6] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.populateReadBuffer Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@3f3904ed:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@2bb2feb7:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=localhost/127.0.0.1:8443 remote=/10.255.106.212:51956]], Read from buffer: [0]
26-Apr-2021 13:03:39.006 FINE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-6] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP request header
    java.io.IOException: Unable to unwrap data, invalid status [CLOSED]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.read(SecureNioChannel.java:657)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1229)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1141)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:795)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:359)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:261)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
26-Apr-2021 13:03:39.006 FINE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.setErrorState Error state [CLOSE_CONNECTION_NOW] reported while processing request
    java.io.IOException: Unable to unwrap data, invalid status [CLOSED]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.read(SecureNioChannel.java:657)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1229)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1141)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:795)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:359)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:261)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
26-Apr-2021 13:03:39.006 FINE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@3f3904ed:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@2bb2feb7:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=localhost/127.0.0.1:8443 remote=/10.255.106.212:51956]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [CLOSED]
26-Apr-2021 13:03:39.006 FINE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.release Pushed Processor [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor@62e6798c]
26-Apr-2021 13:03:39.007 FINE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-6] org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.LimitLatch.countDown Counting down[https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-6] latch=1
26-Apr-2021 13:03:39.007 FINE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-6] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doClose Calling [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint@3e27ba32].closeSocket([org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@3f3904ed:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@2bb2feb7:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=localhost/127.0.0.1:8443 remote=/10.255.106.212:51956]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Well. I think this error is unrelated to my problem.

The final, actual, answer was configuring the server.xml to request the certificates.

```
<SSLHostConfig protocols="TLSv1.2" certificateVerification="required">
```